# Where is storage_path('/app/public/') located exactly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to run this code via command line:

```
public function handle()
    {
        if ( ! File::exists(storage_path('/app/public/examResult/' . $this->argument('file'))) ) {
            dd('Not found this file!');
        }

        Excel::import(new ImportsExamResultImport(), storage_path('/app/public/examResult/' . $this->argument('file')));

        dd('Import excel was successfully');
    }
```

So it basically reads an Excel file which is located at `storage_path('/app/public/examResult/')` directory.

So I placed my Excel file at `laravelproject/app/public/examResult` but when I run the command to execute it, I get this message:

**Not found this file!**

So the question is, where exactly `storage_path` ? Am I putting the file in the right place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up a new project you will want to run :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

That sets up a symbolic link from laravelproject/public/storage to laravelproject/storage

```
storage_path('/app/public')
```

can be found at :

```
laravelproject/storage/app/public
```

Answer (score 0):

configure the file upload path in config/filesystems.php

'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'public')`

public - where want to store your file , please refere for more info(local,s3...)

then run:  php artisan storage:link
you can view the uploaded file via

laravelprojectname/storage/app/public/{filename}

in blade file you can access via : `asset('storage')` / {filename}

for more information please refer https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem